# Code surrounded by try-catch still shows exception warning

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, assert

A line of code that might throw an exception is surronded by try-catch but IntelliJ keeps showsing warning: Method invocation 'getPiece' may produce 'NullPointerException'.

This part of code checks a given spot on the board and needs to find it contains a chess piece and if yes, which one.

```
public void drawBoard() {
    for (...) {
        // square drawing

        Spot spot = Chessboard.checkSpot(x, y);

        Piece piece;
        try {
            piece = spot.getPiece();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            continue;
        }
        g.drawImage(findImage(piece), x, y);
    }
}
```

Surrounding the method invocation with try-catch seemed right to me, but why is IntelliJ still warning me about this.
This is the Spot class just in case.

```
public class Spot {

    private Piece piece;
    private final int positionX;
    private final int positionY;
    private boolean isThreatened;
    private boolean hasPiece;

    public Spot(int positionX, int positionY) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }
    // other stuff..
}
```

checkSpot() method simply goes through a list of spots and drawImage() returns an image for the given piece.

IntelliJ suggests things like Assert 'spot != null' and when I use it in the try-catch above getPiece(), the warning is no longer shown.

Why does assert fix the issue and try-catch statement doesn't? I'm still learning my ropes in programming but this really confuses me.

Comment: is that the full code of the method? Probably missing some part like `if` of similar... (anyway, adding a try-catch will not change the matter, the IDE still thinks that a NPE can be thrown)

Comment: A lot from the method is missing here actually but everything relevant to my question is shown. Seems like yes but still don't know why.

Comment: Catching NPE is almost always the wrong way to write code; instead, if something can be null correctly, you should check it actively and use the appropriate logic.

Comment: @user16320675 I use continue if you mean in the case that the returned value is null

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- understood, I have more research ahead of me :)